# E3 work visa from Melbourne to Minneapolis

Tags: working-visas

I am looking for information on the E3 work visa application process. Any information would be greatly appreciated. I am from Melbourne and will be relocating to Minneapolis with my 12-year-old son. We are hoping to be closer to my older son who is currently on a full football scholarship at the University of Minnesota.

I am currently looking for an employer to sponsor my E3. However not many employers are aware of the E3 visa. Does anyone have any information or are you able to direct or advise me on where to start/get more information (i.e what do I need to apply, processing time, costs etc)? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Questions regarding migration are better suited for our sister site expats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

[U.S. Citizenship and Immigration Services](https://www.uscis.gov/working-united-states/temporary-workers/e-3-certain-specialty-occupation-professionals-australia) is the best source of that information. The State Department link gives details on how to apply, cost, and process. Note that the E-3 visa classification is limited to 10,500 nationals of Australia, and that an employer submits a [Labor Condition Application](https://www.foreignlaborcert.doleta.gov/h-1b.cfm), which can be time comsuming.

> **E-3 Certain Specialty Occupation Professionals from Australia**
>
> The E-3 classification applies only to nationals of Australia. You must be coming to the United States solely to perform services in a specialty occupation. The specialty occupation requires theoretical and practical application of a body of knowledge in professional fields and at least the attainment of a bachelor's degree, or its equivalent, as a minimum for entry into the occupation in the United States.
>
> **Eligibility Criteria**
>
> To qualify for an E-3 visa, you must demonstrate that you:
>
> - Are a national of Australia
> - Have a legitimate offer of employment in the United States
> - Possess the necessary academic or other qualifying credentials
> - Will fill a position that qualifies as a specialty occupation
>
> **Applying for an E-3 Visa from Within the United States**
>
> The Form I-129, Petition for Nonimmigrant Worker is used to apply for a change of status to obtain E-3 nonimmigrant temporary worker classification.
>
> **Supporting Documents**
>
> Your Form I-129 must include the following documents:
>
> - A Labor Condition Application (LCA) which cannot be the same application used in a previous H-1B application.  Until the Department of Labor develops a new LCA for an E-3, the applicant should use the standard ETA-9035 and ask that it be annotated as an E-3 LCA
> - Academic or other credentials demonstrating qualifications for the position
> - Job offer letter or other documentation from the employer establishing that you will be engaged in a specialty occupation and that you will be paid the higher of the actual or prevailing wage
> - If required, before you may commence employment in the specialty occupation, you must have the necessary license or other official permission to practice in the specialty occupation
>     Applying for a Visa With a U.S. Embassy or Consulate
>
> If your petition Form I-129 is approved, we will forward a Form I-797, Notice of Action/Approval to the employer, who in turn will forward it to you. A Form I-797 approval notice is not a U.S. visa, as the visa must be obtained at a U.S. embassy or consulate abroad. After Form I-129 is approved by USCIS, the next step is to apply for a U.S. visa at a U.S. embassy or consulate, generally in your country of residence abroad. Please visit the [Department of State, Travel.state.gov Temporary Workers webpage](https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/employment/temporary-worker-visas.html) for visa information, how-to-apply procedures, and U.S. embassy web contact information to learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell employers that E-3 is similar to the more well-known H-1B, but somewhat easier and only available to Australians. One aspect that's easier is that if you're applying for E-3 from abroad, your employer doesn't have to do Form I-129. If you're applying from in the US, refer to Giorgio's answer.

To compare:

- E-3 from in the US requires LCA and I-129.
- E-3 from abroad requires LCA and E-3 visa.
- H-1B from in the US requires LCA and I-129.
- H-1B from abroad requires LCA, I-129, and H-1B visa.

Having the visa is also necessary if you wish to leave the US and re-enter in the same status.  [This page from the US embassy in the UK](https://uk.usembassy.gov/visas/australian-professional-specialty-visas-e-3/required-documents/) lists the required documents for an E-3 visa, particularly the LCA, job offer and proof of academic/professional qualifications. Strangely, the US embassy in Australia doesn't seem to have a webpage about getting an E-3 visa, but they can probably give you more information if you call them.